# Any ways to Draw SVG?

Tags: graphics

I'm used to the `artist-mode` and though it work decently, i was wondering if it was already possible (with builtin or external library) to draw SVG, either with the mouse, or any other method beside using elisp code to construct it.

I'm aware of a couple project that generate SVG on github, but most if not all construct it with elisp, which isn't really what i want.(while i want to draw it in emacs using either the mouse or keyboard like `artist-mode` does).

Answer (score 3):

There is an interactive SVG generation demo on GitHub: https://github.com/sabof/svg-thing

Honestly though, I recommend you to use a dedicated vector graphics program for the task.  [Inkscape hit version 1.0 recently](https://inkscape.org/news/2020/05/04/introducing-inkscape-10/).

Comment: yeah, i did try inkscape, but i wanted to be able to do it directly in emacs...mostly because i planned to write text directly in the drawn svg, instead of switching application etc.

Comment: funnily enough, i did found [this](https://github.com/jave/inkmacs) but i couldn't make it work. (complain about some of the dbus library being not found)